# C# How to handle an Image exception in a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpclient, html-agility-pack

Using HttpClient with HtmlAgility pack in a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app.

I'd like to know how to manage an exception where an image isn't contained in a particular node.

For example, with missing TEXT, I would use the following:

```
var noTitle = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h3");
if (noTitle == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty((noTitle.InnerText ?? "").Trim()))
    newGame.Title = "Unavailable";
else
    newGame.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h3").InnerText.Trim();
```

But, how do I code this for a missing img src?  My default code, without exception handling is:

```
newGame.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode(".//img[@class= 'box1']").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Ideally, I would like to use my own image file if one is not contained within the node (e.g. "/Assets/Images/Unavailable.png")

Thanks in advance.

31/01/2016 - Added HTML Code

This is a snippet of the HTML I'm getting the info from.

```
<div class="game-c">
    <div class="boxshot">
    <img class="cover" src="http://cover_source" />
    </div>
    <h3 class="h3 white-c">Game Title ...</h3>
    <p>Game description goes here...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="cta-signedOut">...</div>
    <div class="cta-signedIn">
        <a href="https://link.to.store"> 
        <img src="gameImage.gif" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the img src from 'cta-SignedIn'.

Comment: What type is `Cover`? and I assume that you're getting a `NullReferenceException` if the img src doesn't exist?

Comment: What about Contains method on Attributes?

Comment: @ChrisF    public string Cover { get; set; } and yes

Comment: @Filip Could you provide an example please?

Comment: @KeithK you can call Attributes.Contains("src") and if it evaluates false then use your default image since src attribute does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlAgilityPack has `GetAttributeValue()` method which is suitable for your requirement. The 2nd parameter of this method specify default value to be returned when the attribute is not found :

```
newGame.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode(".//img[@class= 'box1']")
                   .GetAttributeValue("src", "/Assets/Images/Unavailable.png");
```

The above snippet assumed that `<img>` element always exists, only it's `src` attribute sometimes missing. Otherwise, you'll need to check whether or not `SelectSingleNode()` returns `null` first.

Here is simple working demo example :

```
var html = @"<div><img/></div>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var src = doc.DocumentNode
             .SelectSingleNode("//img")
             .GetAttributeValue("src", "/Assets/Images/Unavailable.png");
Console.WriteLine(src);
```

<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GdClWQ)</kbd>

**output :**

```
/Assets/Images/Unavailable.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example but it still doesn't work.  It would need to be along the lines of the second example because sometimes the <img> element doesn't exist. The project compiles and runs but it doesn't display src or my own asset.